# Error occured when "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: updates, bug-reporting

MessageBox said that

> Unable to initialize package information.
>
> In the process of initializing the package information, Unable to solve problem has occured.
>
> Including the following error message: 'update-manager' package, please report a bug:
>
> 'E: source list / etc / apt / sources.list the line 6 is incorrect (dist parse)'

It seem to be a some touble.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I doubt the last command will do anything, has trailing spaces.

Comment: Edit your question and add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file and search for the line with the problem with:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In my case, the file contains this in the first seven lines (compare it):

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ubuntu.grn.cat/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.grn.cat/ubuntu/ raring universe main restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

Check if there's a difference. Sometimes due to a corrupted connections I've got errors due to incomplete lines.
Good luck!